# C# WSSE SoapHttpClientProtocol

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsse

I am using a 3rd party Web service in my C# app. I am a total Noob when it comes to WSSE.

When the web service is created it uses SoapHttpClientProtocol as its base class. How do I add WSSE header to this?

I have tried to change the base class to WebServicesClientProtocol (Microsoft.web.services3) instead (as some websites recommend that used that to be able to the usernametoken to the soapcontext) but this results in "Action not supported" exception error.

I am totally lost here. How do I add a WSSE header message (if need be) to a soap message using SoapHttpClientProtocol?

If someone has some code they would like to share this would be awesome.